# what timestamp format is it?

Tags: timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have a sever event with DateTime = DateTime:"2012-08-31T13:27:14.568-07:00", and it's timestamp = Timestamp:"129909184345680927". How are these two correlated?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I can assume one thinks the question lacks context to narrow down possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the number of "ticks" (100ns units [h/t to GolezTrol for a correction], used by several systems for reasonably low-resolution time recording) since 1601-01-01T00:00:00Z

It's handy to start at the beginning of a century, and if you might be dealing with historical data, it's good to go back a long time.

But, with such historical data, you're going to have to come up with some sort of domain-specific system for dates before 1582 when the Gregorian calendar replaced the Julian (though its use didn't come in until different times in different places, with some countries not moving from Julian to Gregorian until the 20th Century). Some use proleptic Gregorian* (act like the Gregorian was always the calendar), some switch to Julian at the point where it was invented, or where a given country being studied did, and those who use proleptic Gregorian don't agree on whether there's a year 0 between 1BCE and 1CE.

So really, since we can't have a one-size-fits-all for dates much earlier than 1582, it makes sense not to try. Better to just take the start of the 17th Century as your "T=0". Hence 1601-01-01T00:00:00Z

Heh. Forgot to say the boring bit. It's used by LDAP, some databases, and others.

*Fun note: Lots of people refer to proleptic Gregorian as "prolaptic Gregorian", which is strange. "Proleptic" is a relatively obscure word for referring to something before it's actual time ("pre-Colonial United States", "England before the Anglo-Saxons"), which makes sense. "Prolaptic" is an even less-used word that's an adjective form of "prolapse" - when an organ moves forward or down from where it should be, which makes no sense. One day I decided to figure out just why this happened. As far as I can make out, it was a spelling mistake in an edition of ISO 8601 that, since it was the first many people had heard of it, caught on.

Comment: I believe this is the kind of timestamp LDAP uses as well, only i believe it is in 100 nanosecond intervals.

Comment: @GolezTrol .NET uses the same approach, internally `DateTime` stores a count of 10µs ticks since 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z proleptic Gregorian.

Comment: @GolezTrol and now I think of it, you're right on the 100ns and that's also true of .NET. I just tried to turn 1/10,000,000 sec into a more readable unit, and made a silly slip. Thanks.

Comment: Also used in Windows FILETIME

Comment: Ah, @craig65535 Thank you! While there are some other uses beyond those, ever since I posted that it's been bugging me that I know there is a case I've dealt with myself more than once and I just couldn't think of what it was. FILETIME. Of course!